# Regular expression to grab all single letters before a period

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex expression to grab all single letters before a period.

For example in the following sentence :

```
a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, d. Donec euismod magna velit, ac tincidunt nisl faucibus eu
```

The regex should grab a and d.

Using

```
/^([^.]+)/
```

I'm able to capture the first `a`, but not the subsequent `d`.

Comment: Try `([^,.]+)\.`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb9WJp/1). Or `[^,.]+(?=\.)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb9WJp/2)).

Comment: Your current regex matches a sequence of characters other than dot from the beginning of a string, which explains why it matches the `a` from your string but nothing else. `^` represents the beginning of a string, `(...)` is a capturing group and could likely be ommited in this context, `[...]` is a character class and `[^...]` in particular define negated character class which match anything but the characters it contains (anything but `.` here), and `+` is a quantifier which defines that the previous token (the character class) should be matched at least 1 time and as many times as possible

Answer (score 0):

For ASCII alphabets [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb9WJp/4):

```
/([a-z])\./mgi
```

For Unicode characters [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb9WJp/3):

```
/(\p{L})\./mg
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you asking for a *lookahead* and the 'g' modifier:

```
console.log(
    "a. Lorem bla bla bla d. Donec euismod,,,"
        .match(/[^.](?=\.)/g)
);
// [ 'a', 'd' ]
```

The `g` modifier is what tells regular expression engine to fetch all matches instead of only first one.

The `(?=\.)` is a *lookahead* assertion claiming (but not matching) for a '.' just after the previous assertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **positive look-ahead** *to to grab all single letters before a period*. SEE [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/18)

```
[a-zA-Z](?=\.)
```